# Jquery autocomplete plugin not showing success response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am using the jquery autocomple plugin like this

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.abc.com/test.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        alert("hello");
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
```

I am not getting any alertbox on success.

The firefox is showing that i getting this as response

```
[{"label":"mark2","value":1},{"label":"abc1","value":20}]
```

Does it expect anything else in return

Comment: why `dataType:jsonp` ? Have you crossdomain problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the [example you've taken this from](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) works fine, and replicating the same example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNyHY/) works as expected, the reason your one is not working is likely that you have a javascript error elsewhere in your page which is stopping further javascript executing.

Also, I replicated the example with your change of just putting an `alert` in the success callback - this also [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/7HMJN/) however you should note that the docs for jQueryUI autocomplete states that:

> It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. **You must always call the response callback** even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Not that that is your error, but it's worth noting!

---

**EDIT** A thought occured to me, if your ajax call is actually generating a server-side error (http500) then you'll never enter the `success` callback, and never get your alert. Try adding an error callback to the ajax call to see if this is the case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.abc.com/test.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        alert("hello");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: that example is also woring fine on my site but only problem is when i chage the URL to my url , then it dont work. i only want to know that what type of data does that `http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON` URL returns , so that i can also return the same data. Currenly my data return looks like above in the question

Comment: You can easily check the return from the geonames service by executing a get request using a browser (eg/ http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&style=full&maxRows=12&name_startsWith=LO). But its not so much what is returned that makes that example work, its how they map the results to the format expected by jQueryUI autocomplete

Comment: that is what i want to know that whats wrong with results in my example. my url return this `[{"label":"mark2","value":1},{"label":"abc1","value":20}]`. even that alert box is not coming

Comment: @john110016 - The response from your method has nothing to do with the alert not showing - as I stated in my answer, if you're not getting the alert its because there is a **javascript** error somewhere in your code. Use jsfiddle.net to recreate the problem you're getting and it'll be alot easier to help you!

Comment: If i use the same URL like geonames , then it works fine. so it means there is no other error. But if i use my URL then i don't get alert box. is that ok or u still say that i have other error

Comment: @john110016 - see updated answer and see if that gives you some clues as to what's going wrong